# How do I get my Spring Aspect to kick in for a @Valid annotation on a service method?

Tags: spring, validation, maven, aspectj

We're using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and Maven 3.0.3.  I'm trying to set up validation of a parameter being passed into a service method.  The method is below.  Notice the `@Valid` annotation.

```java
package org.mainco.subco.mypck.service;

@Service
@RemoteProxy
@Transactional
public class MypckServiceImpl implements MypckService {

    @RemoteMethod
    @Override
    public String myMethod(@Valid final MyObjectDto request) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is the aspect I have set up to help validate the object:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyObjectValidatingAspect extends AbstractDWRAspectValidator<MyObjectDto>
{

    @Before("execution(* org.mainco.subco.mypck.service.MypckService.myMethod(..))")
    public void validateBefore(JoinPoint jp) 
    {
        errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        final MyObjectDto request = validate(jp);
        validateMyObject(request);
        throwErrors();
    }   // validateBefore
```

This is in included in my application context file:

```xml
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

And this is what I've included in the Maven pom.xml file:

```xml
           <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

Unfortunately when the method is invoked, the aspectj's `validateBefore` is never called.  What else do I need to do so that this gets invoked?

Comment: Why invent your own... Spring already provides that functionality for you, you should only need to register the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` in your configuration to enable this. By default it only detects the `@Validated` annotation from Spring but you can just tell it to use the `@Valid` annotation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spring 3.1 there is the [`MethodValidationInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.html) which basically does what you want to achieve yourself. To have this interceptor applied the only thing you need to do is to register a [`MethodValidationPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html) in your application context.

By default it will check for the `@Validated` annotation from Spring but you can instruct it to scan for the `@Valid` annotation.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validatedAnnotationType" value="javax.validation.Valid" />
    <property name="validator" ref="refToYOurLocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
</bean>
```

If you don't specify a `validator` the default JSR-303 validator mechanism will be used (or the more hibernate specific one if that is available). But I can imagine you want to reuse the already configured instance.